# How to set Vacation Message in magento

Tags: cms, magento-1

I need to set a Vacation message in Magento as I will be closing my store for a week.
So far I found that editing text in Demo Store notice works ok. But I am not sure if editing text in Demo Mode and turning it on is a good idea.

Any recommendation how should I proceed ? I only need to put a message, I don't want to turn off checkout.

Comment: Yeah its an good idea.

Comment: Are there any other way to post a vacation message at the top of the website, without actually using Demo Mode ? I read somewhere that Google doesn't like when demo store is turned-on on  the active store, maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Create a static block (CMS > Static Blocks) with the message and add it to the site using widget instances (CMS > Widgets):

Select "CMS Static Block" as type and your theme as Design package/theme:

[image: screenshot]

Then, add a layout update to select where the widget (i.e. the static block) should be shown. To display it on all pages at the top, like the demo store notice, use "All Pages" and "Page Top":

[image: screenshot]

In the "Widget Options" you can select the static block that you have created before. All styling must be done in the static block, the widget instance is just used to add content dynamically to the layout hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I would enable maintenance mode for you site.  You can do this by creating an empty `maintenance.flag` files in the root of your installation.

You can then style your maintenance page to say that the store is offline and will be back at a later date.

Not that this prevents any use of your site.  Product pages will not be available.